# Raspberry Pi Freezes after running Python script for a few hours

Tags: raspbian, python, script, piface

I am using the Pi to check for any weather statements and if it sees a tornado warning it uses a PiFace to set off an alarm. Program is in continuous loop but the problem is raspberry pi freezing every few hours(<24 hr) after starting the script. It will no longer accept input and I have to hard boot.

It is a Model B+ using Ethernet, USB power, 8 GB SD Card, Raspbian, and a PiFace on the GPIO pins using Pi's Power.

Please help, it's fine if it has to reboot but with minimal downtime.

```
import feedparser
import pifacedigitalio as pfio
import time
import smtplib
import datetime
import os

tornado = False
horn = False
strobe = False
_alarm = False
alarmack = False
reset_ = False

mailsent =False
mailalreadysent = False
pfio.init()



while True:
    pfio.digital_write(7,1)
    '''print("------------------------------------------------------------------")'''
     #url = 'http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/us.php?x=1'
    url = 'http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/wwaatmget.php?x=NEC109&y=0'
    feed = feedparser.parse(url)
    '''print (feed.entries[0].title)'''
    if feed.entries[0].has_key("cap_event") is False:

            '''print('Alert: None')'''
            tornado = False


    else:

            '''print ('Alert:', feed.entries[0].cap_event)'''
            if feed.entries[0].cap_event == "Tornado Warning":
                    tornado = True
                    sendmail()

            else:
                    tornado = False

    localtime = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )

    '''print("Tornado Warning:",tornado)'''
    '''print ("Current Local Time:", localtime)'''
    '''print("------------------------------------------------------------------")'''


#ALARM

    if tornado == True:
            _alarm = True
            horn = True
            strobe = True
            '''print("---------------------------------------------------------------------")
            'print("Tornado Warning Issued, TAKE SHELTER... TAKE SHELTER... TAKE SHELTER")
            'print("ALARM ACTIVE")
            'print("---------------------------------------------------------------------")'''

            pfio.digital_write(4,1)
            time.sleep(1)
            pfio.digital_write(4,0)

    else:
            _alarm = False
            horn = False
            strobe = False                
            '''print("---------------------------------------------------------------------")
            'print("No Tornado Warning Issued")
            'print("ALARM INACTIVE")
            'print("---------------------------------------------------------------------")'''



    if pfio.digital_read(0) == 1:
            alarmack= True
    else:
            alarmack = False
    if pfio.digital_read(1) == 1:
            reset_ = True
    else:
            reset_ = False


    #GPIO
    _rly1 = False
    _rly2 = False

    _reset = False
    #while True:
    '''print("---------------------------------------------------------------------")'''
    if reset_ == False:
            if horn == True and alarmack == False:
                    _rly2 = True
                    '''print("Horn: Active")'''
            elif alarmack == True and horn == True:
                    _rly2 = False
                    '''print("Horn: Inactive")'''
                    _rly2 = False
            elif alarmack== False and horn == False:
                    '''print("Horn: Inactive")'''
                    _rly2 = False                                
            if strobe == True:
                    _rly1 = True
                    '''print("Strobe: Active")'''
            else:
                    _rly1 = False
                    '''print("Strobe: Inactive")'''
    else:
            _reset = True
            _rly1 = False
            _rly2 = False
            chirp()
    '''print("---------------------------------------------------------------------")  ''' 



    if _rly1 == True:

            pfio.digital_write(0,1)

    else:

            pfio.digital_write(0,0)


    if _rly2 == True:

            pfio.digital_write(1,1)

    else:

            pfio.digital_write(1,0)



    '''print("---------------------STOP--------------------------")'''
    os.system('clear')



    def chirp():
        pfio.digital_write(5,1)
        time.sleep(1)
        pfio.digital_write(5,0)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how often (per second) is this going to read the wheather service for new data? I don't know the `feedparser` lib but maybe a multitude of requests is performing badly?

Comment: It has been checking continuously with no delay, because if i delay that it will also delay the outputs.

Comment: Have you looked in `/var/log/syslog` to see why the pi appears to "freeze"?

Answer (score 2):

As @Ghanima implied, I don't believe you need to check the url flat out - that's not great for all the other internet users either. Maybe once every 5mins would be enough. You could use something like

```
if time.time() > next_check
    feed = feedparser.parse(url)
    # etc. all the url stuff here
    next_check = time.time() + 300
```

and carry on running the rest of your loop flat out.

Comment: To further emphasize this point, if I were a sys admin at `alerts.weather.gov`, I would temporarily blacklist IPs that continuously polled a service with no delay -- that is tantamount to a DoS attack, even if your machine alone can't pull it off.

Comment: Thank you, I have made my code better so that it calls to NWS less. Like in your suggestion. I haven't been able to test this on my Pi yet, but once I get home in an hour I will.